# Syntax for re.sub with negation

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to use `re.sub` to change '1213' to '1x13' using negation. The syntax should  change whatever character follows a 1 but only if that character is NOT a 3.

The best output I can get is 1x213. But that 2 is still there.

FWIW, I get that with:

```
print(re.sub(r'1(?!3)', '1x', '1213'))
```

What is the right syntax?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you just want:

```
print(re.sub(r'1[^3]', '1x', '1213'))
```

The pattern, `1[^3]` matches anything that is a `1` followed by the character class in brackets, where the `^` just means means its a negated class.

Comment: So the exclamation point is not used for negation? Is it always the carat?

Comment: @HarryBinswanger I'm not a regex guru, but I'm pretty sure that the exclamation by itself doesn't have any special meaning. When you wrote `(?! ...` though, the parenthesis and `?!` together make it a negative look-ahead. The caret itself is actually an anchor which mean "match at the beginning of the line". But, the caret-square-bracket `[^...` opens a *negated class*.

Comment: @HarryBinswanger I usually play around on [here](http://www.regexr.com/) when I'm trying to build a regex. The reference and the cheatsheet are pretty decent.

Comment: Yes, the two meanings of the carat are confusing. I'm now trying to use the negation carat to eliminate replacements for more than one character, but not succeeding. I would think [^33] would allow replacement if the target has 34, but I don't seem to get that. I.e., I have re.sub(r'1[^(33)]', '1x', '12134') but it doesn't replace anything but the 2. I tried with and without the parens around the 33.

Comment: @HarryBinswanger the caret negates *everything* in the brackets. Having `33` in brackets is equivalent to `3`. So, you want to replace any *number* except a 3?

Comment: then why doesn't re.sub(r'1[^33]', '1x', '12135') replace the 35 with x?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138857/discussion-between-harry-binswanger-and-juanpa-arrivillaga).

Answer (score 2):

Use a negated character class and positive look-behind:

```
In [45]: re.sub('(?<=1)[^3]', 'x', s)
Out[45]: '1x13'
```

`[^3]` will match every character except 3 and `(?<=1)` makes sure that your character follows a 1.